# Scheduled Timer Task does not execute

Tags: java, android, timertask

The `timeRemaining` variable is a string representing an integer in the range 0-10. What I want to accomplish is run the timerTask for a period of `timeRemaining` seconds, then move on to the following code which starts with `i++`. However, when I run this method the `i++` section executes immediately and the timer task does not execute at all. Its basically supposed to count down from `timeRemaining` to 0 and decrement the time to 0 and then move on with the remainder of the code.

```
public void resumeSlideShow(Integer i, final String timeRemaining, int offset) {
    timer = new Timer();
    Button time_rem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_rem);
    time_rem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hex_filled);
    final TimerTask finish_photo = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SlideShow.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView time_rem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_rem);
                    int timeRem = Integer.parseInt(timeRemaining);
                    timeRem--;
                    time_rem.setText(Integer.toString(timeRem));
                    if (timeRem == 0) {
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }});
        }};
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(finish_photo,0,1000);
    i++;
    if (i < imageDisplayerArrayList.size()) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        slideshow(imageDisplayerArrayList, i, offset, timeRemaining);
    }
    else {
        timer.cancel();
        Intent qa = new Intent(SlideShow.this,ViewScreen.class);
        startActivity(qa);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: It is very likely that `timer.cancel()` gets executed before the `finish_photo`  task. Try to wait on main thread and notify from timer task to see if this is the case.

Comment: Can you please provide a short code snippet on how to do this